# unable to access spring boot application deployed in centos 9 server : request time out

Tags: spring-boot, centos

My application was developed in Spring Boot, MySql. My server is running on CentOS 9 Stream. port 8080 is ocupied by Jenkins. So I have deployed it in a different port 8081. But my problem is when I am trying to access the API from the postman, it is taking a long time and at last showing message request time out.

How I can resolve it?

I am also facing the same issue in the time when trying to access the MySQL from DBear, it is taking a long time to connect and after that telling that request time out.

After searching in the i think the issue is with the port availability from the server. Guide me so that when I will deploy an application it will be available. I am also Apache web server.

Comment: There could be hundreds of things causing this.  If your service started up and you are seeing a message in the logs that indicate it's up and listening on port 8081, then I would check your firewall rules and make sure the port is allowing connections.  I'm not sure what you mean by you are also using Apache web server or that you can't connect to MySQL from DBear (whatever this is).  Try narrowing the scope of your question, and maybe include why you think apache and MySQL are relevant.  My guess, it's the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have some rules on 8181 port, to check all the policy on Linux firewall get all the rules of iptables in cent-OS by this command.

sudo iptables -S